# Database connection times - PostGreSQL vs Oracle (ArcSDE)

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I have 2 SDE instances.

- Both have the same amount of data (2000 datasets both raster and
  vector).
- One is PostGreSQL 9.2 with ArcSDE 10.2.1
- One is Oracle 11g with ArcSDE 10.2.1

So basically the only difference is the RDBMS.
The oracle instance takes 5 seconds to open in ArcCatalog.
The PostGreSQL instance takes 26 seconds to open in ArcCatalog.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how we can get PostGreSQL instance to open just as fast as the Oracle one.

Comment: related Tune Postgres http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407442/optimise-postgresql-for-fast-testing

Comment: Tried most of that @Mapperz

Answer (score 1):

1) Are the two databases running on similar hardware?

2) Have you tuned the Postgres server?  By default Postgres is configured to run using minimal resources. That's good because you won't swamp your server just by setting it up, but it handicaps Postgres when you start to try to do real work.  As a start here are two links to the Postgres Wiki to get you started on which settings can be tweaked for better performance:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization

Comment: You work up some initial, quick & dirty config values here: http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/

Comment: Each database runs on it's own seperate VM (HyperV).